# How do I implement an Iterator adapter only for iterators with a specific Item?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a custom adapter for `Iterator`:

```
use std::iter::Iterator;

struct LexIter<Iter> {
    last_char: Option<char>,
    iter: Iter,
}

impl<Iter> LexIter<Iter> {
    fn put_back(&mut self, ch: char) {
        self.last_char = Some(ch);
    }
}

impl<Iter: Iterator> Iterator for LexIter<Iter> {
    type Item = char;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<char> {
        match self.last_char {
            Some(ch) => {
                let res = ch;
                self.last_char = None;
                Some(res)
            }
            None => self.iter.next(),
        }
    }
}

impl<Iter: Iterator> std::convert::From<Iter> for LexIter<Iter> {
    fn from(it: Iter) -> Self {
        LexIter {
            last_char: None,
            iter: it,
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get this error

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
18 |         match self.last_char {
   |         ^ expected char, found associated type
   |
   = note: expected type `std::option::Option<char>`
   = note:    found type `std::option::Option<<Iter as std::iter::Iterator>::Item>`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
  --> src/main.rs:24:21
   |
24 |             None => self.iter.next(),
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand that `self.iter.next()` returns `Option<Iter::Item>`, but I just want to make an adapter for those iterators which has `Iterator::Item` as `char`.

Is there way to specify the type explicitly in the function's signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a value for the *associated type* `Item` in your trait bounds:

```
impl<Iter> Iterator for LexIter<Iter>
    where Iter: Iterator<Item = char>
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Additionally:

1. I believe your implementation can be simplified to

   ```
   fn next(&mut self) -> Option<char> {
       self.last_char.take().or_else(|| self.iter.next())
   }
   ```
2. It looks like you are implementing something very close to the [`Peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html) adapter; perhaps you can use that instead.
3. If not, you can use [`put_back`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.5.5/itertools/fn.put_back.html) from the awesome Itertools crate.

Comment: and no, `Peekable` doesn't suit, I need to have an ability to __put one character back to stream__ but not __get next char without advancing interator__

Comment: Ah, that's what itertools' putback adaptor does actually.

Comment: @bluss my gut tells me that they are isomorphic, but one might suit a particular coding style more than another. Is one more "powerful" than the other?

Comment: I've only ever used them in a way that's equivalent, but isn't put back more powerful since you can put “back” any value, not just the most recent one?

Comment: @bluss I need put back just one symbol anyway. Of course itertools is more powerful but in this way I haven't a chance to reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: Your LexIter is equivalent, so it and PutBack are both more powerful than peekable. (It's mostly a matter of curiosity.)